# How to wire up 6 pin potentiometers

Tags: led, control, potentiometer, volume

How can I wire up 6 pin potentiometers for 3 pins.
I need a 3 pin potentiometer for a project, but I only have 6 pin ones available, how can I hook it up to a LED or volume control circuit?
[image]

Comment: just use one group of three pins and ignore the other group.

Answer (score 4):

That six pin pot is really just two normal three pin pots controlled by the same shaft.

Each PC board is one pot, so you just wire to one board as you would for a normal single pot - there should be no internal connections between the two pots.

Answer (score 3):

It's a dual-potentiometer (e.g. volume control for a stereo amplifier).

The volume control wiring is shown for one channel and is to be duplicated for the other.

[image]