# 6 Pin Potentiometer

Tags: circuit-design, pcb-design, potentiometer

I have a 6 Pin Potentiometer. I know that the 3 pins are separately a potentiometer and the other three pins are a part of other potentiometer. My question is what will happen if I externally short the pins, i.e., 1-to-1, 2-to-2 and 3-to-3 and then use 1-3 as input and 2 as output? Will the circuit be short or is it just going to work fine?
[image]

Reference: vu2nan (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/193409/vu2nan), How to wire up 6 pin potentiometers, URL (version: 2020-09-12): https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/521166

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason such 'gang' potentiometers exist is to be able to handle multiple signals with one manual control. Prime example for a 2-gang pot: a stereo volume control.

If you short the two pots together as you propose, you will get:

- overall (pin 1 to pin 3) resistance will be halved
- wiper (pin 2 to 1/3) resistance will be an average of each wiper, halved

So if your pots are a linear 10k and you have the wiper at midpoint, shorting them as you propose will be:

- 5k, pins 1-3
- 2.5k pins 2 to pins 1
- 2.5k pins 2 to pins 3

A more complex model would account for any offset between them, but you get the basic point: you've turned a 10k gang pot into a single 5k one.

Nothing 'bad' will happen if you short them, but there isn't a particular advantage of doing so either. If you only need one channel it's a waste of money to use a gang pot.

Comment: Would it reduce the resistance noise when moving the wiper(s)?

Comment: Pots tend to get scratchy with age and use. If that's a concern having two in parallel won't make things so much better, as each pot is in the same environment.

Comment: I thought your response might be to buy a better pot in the first place; that's an aspect I wasn't thinking of.

Comment: Also, consider that if you have a pair in parallel and just one of them gets scratchy, it will still cause the output to be scratchy as you have one wiper alternating between open and wiper value. So you still haven't solved the problem, while the solution would be the same: get out the contact cleaner and soak that pot.

Answer (score 2):

That is the equivalent of putting resistors in parallel. Assuming pots are equal, the pot would behave like a pot of half value. The general case is shown here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPhgFi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The end-to-end resistance will be approximately half of the individual end-to-end resistances. The combined wiper resistance to an end will be approximately proportional to its position (with any taper taken into account), just like in a regular potentiometer. I say "approximately" because the gang error may cause additional deviations from the original resistance taper.  It's usually slight since the gangs are designed to operate together, but they're not designed to be paralleled.